# How to inherit dynamic data from parent to child WITHOUT re-render it, for example a map?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

We won't re-render a map just because of change in the data that the map presents, obviously:

```
const [points, setPoints] = useState([]);

useEffect(() => {

  const someFunc = points => setPoints(points);

  pointsSub(someFunc);

  return function() {
    pointsUnSub(someFunc)
  }
}, [points]);

return (<Map points={points} />);
```

So what are we doing in such a situation? Passing the listener to the Map component itself like this:

```
<Map points={points} pointsSub={pointsSub} />
```

Comment: If you not render then how would you know which props you have passed